# How to decrease the height of a "longtable"?

Tags: booktabs

I have the following problem. I have the following code and now I want to achieve that the table is not shown on a new page, but under the section heading, so that the table is shortened vertically a bit. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccccccccccccccccccc@{}}
                    \toprule \toprule 
                                        & & & & & & & &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
\\\multicolumn{23}{c}{\textbf{Modell 1}}\\
                    \midrule
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=4$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=8$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=12$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=16$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=20$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=24$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=28$}  \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-16} \cmidrule(lr){17-19}
                    \cmidrule(lr){20-22}
                    & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max \\
                    \midrule
&I&A&A&S&D&F&C&D&W&Q&D&F&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&\\
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\                \midrule 
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
                    \multicolumn{23}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}}\\
                    \midrule
                                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=4$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=8$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=12$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=16$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=20$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=24$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=28$}  \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-16} \cmidrule(lr){17-19}
                    \cmidrule(lr){20-22}
                    & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max & Min & Median & Max\\\midrule
                    &I&A&A&S&D&F&C&D&W&Q&D&F&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&\\
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
                    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\                    \bottomrule
                    \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
                \vspace{0.1cm}
                \footnotesize \emph{Note:} 
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is placing the `\section` directive inside the `sidewaystable` environment an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

If placing the section inside the `sidewaystable` environment is an option for you, the following solution should be of interest to you. Note that it does *not* resort to the `adjustbox` visual sledgehammer to limit the width of the table to `\textwidth`. It doesn't double up on `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` statements either.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\section{A}

\begin{threeparttable}
\small % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Caption}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{21}{c} }
\\[1\baselineskip]
\multicolumn{21}{c}{\textbf{Modell 1}}\\[1ex]
\toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=4$}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=8$} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=12$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=16$} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=20$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=24$} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=28$}  \\
\cmidrule{1-3}   \cmidrule{4-6}   \cmidrule{7-9} 
\cmidrule{10-12} \cmidrule{13-15} \cmidrule{16-18}
\cmidrule{19-21}
  Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max 
& Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max 
& Min & Med & Max \\
\midrule
I&A&A&S&D&F&C&D&W&Q&D&F&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C\\
\bottomrule
 \\
 \\
\multicolumn{21}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}}\\[1ex]
\toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=4$}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=8$} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=12$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=16$} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=20$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=24$} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$T=28$}  \\
\cmidrule{1-3}   \cmidrule{4-6}   \cmidrule{7-9} 
\cmidrule{10-12} \cmidrule{13-15} \cmidrule{16-18}
\cmidrule{19-21}
  Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max 
& Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max & Min & Med & Max 
& Min & Med & Max\\
\midrule
I&A&A&S&D&F&C&D&W&Q&D&F&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C&C\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
\footnotesize 
\emph{Notes.} \dots
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```